# How can I Implement react-native-data-table?

Tags: reactjs, listview, react-native

Can any one guide me how can I implement this library.
Basically I want to Implement basic table with paggination.

Answer (score 0):

A better option is to use `DataTable` from `react-native-paper`.

You can find an example on how to use it [here](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/data-table.html).

Comment: I am looking for react-native-data-table react-native-paper does not fullfil my requirement